# Project in Codelite not compiling

Tags: c++, windows, codelite

I am using Codelite 5.3 on Windows 7. I created a new workspace and added a new project in it. But when I try tobuild the project, Codelite is not compiling and ends with the Build Message:

`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin /c "mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile"`

Nothing else. When I run the project, empty Output window appears (which happens when the project isn't built properly, still the project is run).

What should I do to fix this?

When I tried adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` in environmental variable `Path`, and tried to Build, then the Build Output I got is:

`Failed to start build process, command: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin /c "mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile", process terminated with exit code: 0C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin /c "mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build command:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin /c "mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile"
```

is nonsense. It should be:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "mingw32-make.exe -j 4 -e -f  Makefile"
```

where `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` is the system shell. But:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin
```

is not even the pathname of any executable file, or even a pathname. It appears to be
a `PATH`-like value invalidly prefixed with the name of the shell.

CodeLite (quite properly) obtains the shell name `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` from the value of the system environment variable `ComSpec`.

I believe the only way this in which this mess could have occurred is that the value of `ComSpec` has been trashed on the system before CodeLite runs.

Navigate **Control Panel** -> **System and Security** -> **System**
-> **Advanced system settings** -> **Environment Variables** and inspect `ComSpec` in the **System variables**. Also look for `ComSpec` or `COMSPEC` in the **User variables** in case a an overriding value has been set up there. If the value is not `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` then correct it.